# VBA to maintain format during copy paste

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macros enabled workbook(protected sheets).
Users are allowed to provide the inputs to the cells that are unlocked.

The problem here is when users copy paste the data from other applications, it will overwrite the format used on an existing sheet, which is creating a hassle.

Is it possible to keep the format even when users copy/paste?

Comment: A (heavy) workaround, you could use `Worksheet_Change` event to get the value of the paste, then use UNDO to get back your format and put back the value in the cell.

Comment: There are many examples on the internet like http://superuser.com/questions/392507/prevent-excel-2010-user-from-pasting-formatting-into-cell or https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/575750-restrict-paste-paste-values-using-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: Another option would be to keep a copy of the worksheet hidden, with all the formatting and none of the data. Then a `Worksheet_change` event copies the formatting from the hidden 'buffer' back to the changed cell(s).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.I am not getting an option to proceed further here..please help...1. I want to get the format (font, font size, alignment)  2. use the same on all the data that uses paste from other applications. So, I am not sure how to catch all the info I need and how to push it on to newly inserted data. Kindly help me with demo code if possible

Answer (score 0):

1) Create custom styles for various formatting used on your sheet and (if possible) name ranges which are "styled"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("STYLE")).Count = Target.Count Then
    Target.Style = "STYLE"
End If

End Sub
```

This code will check, if changed cells are "inside" of styled range. If all changed cells are inside the styled range - apply the style. If you keep the range naming consistent with style naming you can use a loop to go through.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. It recognizes if someone pastes into the range of cells, undoes the paste, and repastes matching the destination formatting

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:D12")) Is Nothing Then
    If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True Then
        Dim UndoString As String
        UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
        If Left(UndoString, 5) = "Paste" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            Target.Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If
```